# Differences in cachebuster implementations

Tags: javascript, caching

"Implementation" might be an awful strong word, but I wrote some "code" to do cachebusting for a javascript ad serving implementation.

I did it with what I presumed was the shortest and most obvious method:

```
var cachebuster=Date.now();
```

And then append that to the .js query string. I got an e-mail from the ad vendor stating that all script requests had to now include this bit of code:

```
var cachebuster=Math.round(Math.random() * 100000);
```

Presumably the vendor doesn't know we were already doing our own and it was just a form letter. However I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. This seems like a much dumber implementation (you have a chance of a random number coming up twice and therefore getting a cached script, plus it's longer and slower*), but it came from the vendor who presumably knows what they're doing. Any reason to go their route, instead of mine?

*albeit imperceptibly

Comment: Maybe they expect to receive more than 1 request at the same millisecond.

Comment: Isn't the cachebuster so that the client doesn't cache the URL?

Comment: When looking at the cache the query string is accounted for, the cache buster idea is to defeat any cache. Say `www.example.com/resource` is the resource you want voiding the cache and it is fetched with a GET method you could do `www.example.com/resource?some_url_component` and `www.example.com/resource?other_url_component` and they are two different resources to cache checking and will both be a cache miss. This strategy assumes the query string is ignored server side. You usually will see something like `www.example.com/resource?cb=this_arg_is_ignored&actual_param=value&...`.